# OrderBy(Int64) and IPagedList is not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc web application, which display paging of records, ordered by a PartialTag column which is of type biginit:-

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = "", int page = 1)
        {
string withOutSpace = searchTerm.Trim();
int pagesize;
bool succeed = int.TryParse(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TechPageSize"], out pagesize);
var racks = repository.AllFindRacks_j(withOutSpace).OrderBy(a => a.Technology.PartialTag).ToPagedList(page, pagesize);

return View(racks);
        }
```

Currently I am getting wrong order by using the PartialTag colum which is of type Biginit.  for example the order will be

- 1002055
- 1002056
- 100334
- 100335

Instead of being:-

- 100334
- 100335
- 1002055
- 1002056

While if I remove the ToPagedlist and display the record without paging then they will have the right order. Can anyone advice please what is causing this problem ?
Thnaks

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it is a big int? Because it orders as a string.

Comment: yes on sql server 2008R2 it is a bigint that allow nulls, and when i use entity framework to map the table it automatically use Nullable<Long> ..

Comment: Could you show us the code for `ToPagedList(...)` or where it comes from? It could be that it applies an `OrderBy` instead of a `ThenBy` disregarding your `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: i am using the most populat paging list for asp.net mvc web project , here is the link http://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedListExt/

Comment: I cannot directly find any source code, but perhaps you can work around it by doing `.OrderBy(a => a.Technology.PartialTag).Select(x => x).ToPagedList(page, pagesize);` which looks odd, but I have used it for concatenating `OrderBy` when I didn't know how many filters I had. So the key there is `Select(x => x)` after the `OrderBy(..)`